# Showing subset of website to user with not enough permission

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am developing app in backbone which requires UI elements [Menus,Table,Table-any-field] to be visible depending upon access level .Example Email-ID fields should not be shown to anyone except Admin.

Is there any standard approach to implement this kind of functionality?
For action level like [edit ,delete,bookmark] etc I get permission list from server.Which I use to show/hide particular action.But I am in doubt how to implement something similar for enitre app UI.

I think StackOverflow implements similar such thing where option to add comment are hidden till user has enough points.Any Idea how they achieve this?

Comment: _"anyone except Admin"_ - I'd suggest function-level access control, not role-based access control. That is, in the application use something like `if (hasAccess('email')) { ...` and _not_ something like `if (hasRole('admin') { ...`. That way you don't need any code changes if requirements change and suddenly some other users (besides Admin users) need to see Email-IDs. Your second paragraph implies you're already doing this, but if so what is the problem?

Comment: I have multiple role in app Admin was just an example. Also I want to able to hide what fields he can see on table or what tab are visible to him

Comment: My point still applies. Don't code the app to control access to individual controls based on _role._ The concept I described will give you the same end effect, but the code will be much easier to maintain.